# How do I debug a GP Service in ArcServer?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, debugging

I have a geoprocessing service that was successfully published to our ArcServer instance.
I'm using 10.1 which means we could not publish unless it actually worked run as a tool in ArcMap.  But now when I try calling form my client I'm not getting anything.  And the messages provided in ESRI logging are not very helpful.  I tried attaching to the ArcGIS server service but I never had my breakpoints reachable.  So what do I attach to in order to listen for exceptions???

Comment: Before you start trying to do real debugging: 1) whats the error being thrown 2) have you installed/registered your dll on the server machine  -- most of the times a 'custom tool not working as a gp service' is a registration issue.

Comment: All of our services are in a common dll which was registered properly.  This way when one service works they all should work.  As to the error it is conflicting.  On the client all I get is : Calling Service.  Executing...  Failed.  On the server I get a log that I received my parameters successfully.  But in Fiddler I get an HTTP 400.

Comment: I'm now past the http 400 error.  But there is no exception thrown that is visible to me.  I just get a message that the service failed.  On server logging I tried adding logging to the server log but the log entries do not show up.  No exception, not error messages, no way to see my service messages, and now logging is a no go as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very, very long and agonizing process we finally have the cause.  I'm putting it here so that no one spends another 3-4 months figuring it out.

Each object type has it's own fields and you can see these fields in the Schema for the shape in Arc Catalog.  For a Point it is simple, OBJECTID and SHAPE.  For a Polygon (my two optional fields) there are a total of 4 fields that MUST be populated.  Unfortunately, if they are not populated then ESRI just fails.  No log.  No exception.  No nothing.

So when passing a Polygon it was necessary to pass 4 fields:  OBJECTID (which must be non-zero), SHAPE, SHAPE_Area (we set this to 0.0), and SHAPE_Length (we set this to 0.0 also).

Once we populated all 4 ESRI fields, the service call was successful!!!  And it took 4 months to solve it and ESRI support provided no support on this issue.  In fact, I had at least 3 (and maybe 4) support people explicitely tell me my parameter setup was just fine.